# Graphql Ruby - Cannot read property 'types' of undefined at buildClientSchema - rails 6 API only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, ruby-on-rails-6, graphiql

I get this error on load when I try to load the graphiql client with Rails 6, specifically wanting to use the Documentation Explorer.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'types' of undefined
at buildClientSchema (http://localhost:3000/assets/graphiql/rails/application-6f03c7a92432765b0fbe671bfb7a292ee6c37e6704b6e6ac95587e45676bbf72.js:34102:72)
at http://localhost:3000/assets/graphiql/rails/application-6f03c7a92432765b0fbe671bfb7a292ee6c37e6704b6e6ac95587e45676bbf72.js:2795:55
```

I tried deleting my graphql directory and re-doing the rails generate graphql:install.

I am using

- rails 6
- graphiql-rails (1.7.0)
- graphql (1.10.5)

I originally built it as API only (and removed unnecessary files, including the assets) but then added the necessary configurations to run graphiql in local development, including adding an app/assetts/config/manifest.js with

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

I was able to look into it more - I made a breakpoint in the chrome debugger for line 34,102, which has the following code:

```
function buildClientSchema(introspection, options) {
  // Get the schema from the introspection result.
  var schemaIntrospection = introspection.__schema;

  // Converts the list of types into a keyMap based on the type names.
  var typeIntrospectionMap = (0, _keyMap2.default)(schemaIntrospection.types, function (type) {
    return type.name;
  });
..... more code ......
```

The issue is with `schemaIntrospection.types`, `schemaIntrospection` is undefined. So above, I inspected the introspection variable which calls `introspection.__schema` - The introspection variable looked like:

```
{"Schema":
    {"queryType": {"name":"Query"},
     "mutationType": {"name":"Mutation"},
     "subscriptionType":null,
.... more JSON ...
```

So, what I ended up doing is instead of having `var schemaIntrospection = introspection.__schema;`, I set the `schemaIntrospection` variable using the correct key:

```
var schemaIntrospection = introspection.Schema;
```

And it worked! ***For that specific call only :/*** , as I had used the interactive debugger

**Does anyone know how I can fix this with ruby-graphql/graphiql more permanently?**

I want to be able to use the Documentation Explorer

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Circling back, I was migrating from a REST based API to Graphql. My old project had a middleware (https://github.com/vigetlabs/olive_branch) which I had forgotten to disable, so this was causing it to auto change snake case (which it identified `__schema` as snake case) to CamelCase. My bad about this, but wanted to follow up in case anyone else had issues, maybe check your middlewares.